# Using JavaScript get addition of the two strings which having same characters occurs and returns remaining as it is

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

I need to make addition of the two strings which having number and character combinations. Matched characters attached numbers should get add and other string should remains same.

```js
let string1 = '2B+3P+7R+1E';
let string2 = '3B+4A+5P';
let concatStrings = string1.concat('+'+string2);
let splitString = concatStrings.split('+');
let newArray = [];
let tempArray = []
splitString.map(x1 => {
    let combData = x1.match(/(\d+)(\w+)/);
    let numbersOnly = combData[1];
    let lettersOnly = combData[2];

    if(!tempArray.includes(lettersOnly)){
        tempArray.push(lettersOnly);
    }
    
    newArray.push({num:numbersOnly,char:lettersOnly})

});

const res = Object.values(newArray.reduce((a, { num, char }) => {
    a[num] = a[num] || { num, char: new Set() };
    a[num].char.add(char);
    return a;
  }, {})).map(({ num, char }) => ({ num, char: [...char].join(",")}));
  
  console.log(res);
  
  //Output should print 5B+8P+4A+7R+1E
  //sequence should not matter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're grouping the pairs by value there, you want to combine them by key.

As the whole snippet was, frankly, kindof a mess, I rewrote your logic completely. You can now pass any number of strings to the `addStrings` function.

```js
function addStrings(...strings) {
  // We're going to store our summed values in here.
  const summed = {};

  // For every input string
  strings.forEach(str => {
    // Split the string up into separate key/value pairs
    str.split('+')
      .forEach((pair) => {
        // Extract the key and the value for each pair
        const [count, key] = pair.split('');
        // And add that to the summed value, making sure to parse the count to a integer.
        summed[key] = (summed[key] || 0) + parseInt(count, 10);
      });
  });

  // Now convert all summed entries into pairs, and join them into a string.
  return Object.entries(summed)
    .map(([k, v]) => v + k)
    .join('+');
}

console.log(addStrings('2B+3P+7R+1E', '3B+4A+5P'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea, to first concatenate the strings and to use a regex for extracting the values and names, was good.

You could then split the task into parts. Create a function to:

- decode the string into pairs
- combine the pairs into an object, grouped by name, and related sums
- encode that object into a string

Code:

```js
const toPairs = (str) => Array.from(str.matchAll(/(\d+)([^+]+)/g));
const toString = (obj) => Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => v + k).join("+");
const toObject = (pairs) => pairs.reduce((acc, [, v, k]) => 
    Object.assign(acc, { [k]: (acc[k] ?? 0) + +v }), {});  

// demo
let string1 = '2B+3P+7R+1E';
let string2 = '3B+4A+5P';
let result = toString(toObject(toPairs([string1, string2].join("+"))));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Instead of the `[s1,s2].join('+')`, you could also just concatenate them.

Comment: Yes, you could, but this keeps with the format of the original strings. If we drop that `+`, we might as well drop them from the input as well. And my implementation of `toPairs` requires the `+` to be there. This allows the *name* part to be *identifiers* which may include digits (just not in first position).

Comment: Oh I meant with a `+`. I was kinda confused that the `join` was inside the parenthesis, but that's actually quite clever. (My `.join` is the _last_ operation to build the result string, where you use it to transform the input)